# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of Undefined in React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, indexof

```
  const categories = this.props.categories.data.filter(
  (i)=>{
  return i.svcName.string.indexOf(this.state.search) !== -1;
});
```

I get the Error Cannot read property 'indexOf' of Undefined in React-Redux.
Should I include any import statements or is there a alternate. Thanks in advance

**Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const { data } = this.props.categories;
const categories = data.filter((item, i) => {
  const { svcName } = item;
  return svcName.toLowerCase().search(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
});
```

Just make sure that your `this.state.search` is not `undefined` or `null`. Also make sure that inside your `filter` method that `i.svcName.string` exists and is not some bogus key/values.

Comment: Thank you Bro, but still the same issue. this.state.search & i.svcName is defined.

Comment: i.svcName.string, what is ```string``` in this? is this a key in the data. Try consoling string in your filter method.

Comment: No, checked for references and found that string can be included front of indexOf to work. But with and without string , same result is coming

Comment: can you share the data model of this.props.categories.data,  as in what does this array contain.

Comment: [{"id":1,
"active":true,
"createdBy":"system"
,"createdTime":12321,
"updatedBy":null
,"updatedTime":null,
"svcCode":1,
"svcName":"Names"

The Api looks like this

Comment: Hi, I have updated this answer. This should work. It is working at my end. Hope this helps. If this is working kindly mark this is the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, that works when i tried with an another example. But there is some issues in my code. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154737/discussion-between-premkumar-and-adeel-imran).